# Compilation error when I tried to build packages for NumPy and SciPy using Clang that I built from sources

Tags: python, clang, cross-compiling, python-wheel

I tried to build wheel packages of NumPy and SciPy using Clang and Clang++ for RISC-V. I used cross-compilation on Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL.

Firstly, I built from sources LLVM from the standard repository, RISC-V GCC Toolchain from the branch rvv-next, and used these toolchains to build the latest OpenBLAS from sources.

After this, I install the virtual environment of a cross-compilation, and activated it.
Next, I installed necessary Python packages, and started building NumPy and SciPy.

As a result, I got the wheel package for NumPy, but the compilation error instead of the wheel package for SciPy. The compilation error is

```bash
  scipy/spatial/qhull.c:10158:72: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'void (*)(qhT *, void *, vertexT *, vertexT *, setT *, unsigned int)' (aka 'void (*)(struct qhT *, void *, struct vertexT *, struct vertexT *, struct setT *, unsigned int)') to parameter of type 'printvridgeT' (aka 'void (*)(struct qhT *, struct _IO_FILE *, struct vertexT *, struct vertexT *, struct setT *, unsigned int)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
    (void)(qh_eachvoronoi_all(__pyx_v_self->_qh, ((void *)__pyx_v_self), (&__pyx_f_5scipy_7spatial_5qhull__visit_voronoi), (__pyx_v_self->_qh[0]).UPPERdelaunay, qh_RIDGEall, 1));
```

The file scipy/spatial/qhull.c was generated by Cython, when the build process was running.

More precisely, I did like this:

```bash
cd ~
mkdir wheels-clang
cd wheels-clang
mkdir other-blas scripts
./scripts/build_gcc_and_clang.sh "$HOME/wheels-clang"
./scripts/download_build_and_install_openblas_using_llvm_toolchain.sh "$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas" "$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr"

export SYSROOT=/opt/riscv/sysroot
export RISCV_GCC=$HOME/wheels-clang/scripts/llvm-clang-wrapper.sh
export RISCV_GPP=$HOME/wheels-clang/scripts/llvm-clang++-wrapper.sh
export RISCV_GFORTRAN=/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gfortran
export RISCV_LD=/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-ld
export RISCV_AR=/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar

path-to-ubuntu-wsl-python3.9.14/bin/python3 -m pip install crossenv

path-to-ubuntu-wsl-python3.9.14/bin/python3 -m crossenv --cc $RISCV_GCC --cxx $RISCV_GPP --ar $RISCV_AR path-to-riscv-python3.9.14/bin/python riscv_cross_venv_stock
source riscv_cross_venv_stock/bin/activate
build-pip install wheel cython pybind11 pythran ply beniget gast pythran numpy==1.19.3
pip install wheel cython pybind11 pythran ply beniget gast pythran numpy==1.19.3

git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.7.3 --depth 1 https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
cd scipy/
echo '[openblas]' > site.cfg
echo 'libraries = openblas' >> site.cfg
echo "library_dirs = $HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib" >> site.cfg
echo "include_dirs = $HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/include" >> site.cfg
echo "runtime_library_dirs = $HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib" >> site.cfg

export BLAS_DIR=$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/
export OPEN_BLAS_DIR=$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/
export F90=$RISCV_GFORTRAN
export F77=$RISCV_GFORTRAN
export LD=$RISCV_LD
export CC=$HOME/wheels-clang/scripts/llvm-clang-wrapper.sh
export CXX=$HOME/wheels-clang/scripts/llvm-clang++-wrapper.sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -I$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib/pkgconfig"
export BLAS=$HOME/wheels-clang/other-blas/OpenBLAS/usr/lib/libopenblas.so

pip wheel . -v -w ../wheels_stock
cd ..
cp riscv_cross_venv_stock/cross/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a riscv_cross_venv_stock/build/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a
cp riscv_cross_venv_stock/cross/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/lib/libnpyrandom.a riscv_cross_venv_stock/build/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/lib/libnpyrandom.a
cd scipy/
pip wheel . -v -w ../wheels_stock
```

I used the following scripts:

1. the script build_gcc_and_clang.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function install_prerequisites()
{
    sudo apt -y install autoconf automake autotools-dev
    sudo apt -y install libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev
    sudo apt -y install build-essential
    sudo apt -y install bison flex
    sudo apt -y install curl python3
    sudo apt -y install texinfo gperf libtool patchutils bc
    sudo apt -y install zlib1g-dev libexpat-dev
    sudo apt -y install make cmake git-all
}

function create_installation_dirs()
{
    sudo mkdir /opt/riscv
    sudo chown -R $USER /opt/riscv
}

function download_and_build_gcc()
{
    git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain --branch rvv-next
    cd riscv-gnu-toolchain/
    ./configure --with-arch=rv64gcv --prefix=/opt/riscv --enable-linux
    make linux
}

function download_and_build_llvm()
{
    git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project
    cd llvm-project
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/riscv -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="RISCV" -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE="riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;llvm;lld;flang" ../llvm
    make -j4
    make install
}

DIR_FOR_SOURCES="$1"
if [ -z "$DIR_FOR_SOURCES" ]
then
    DIR_FOR_SOURCES="$HOME"
fi

echo "The parent directory for GCC and LLVM sources: $DIR_FOR_SOURCES"
install_prerequisites
create_installation_dirs
cd "$DIR_FOR_SOURCES"
download_and_build_gcc
cd ..
download_and_build_llvm
cd ..
```

2. the script download_build_and_install_openblas_using_llvm_toolchain.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function clone_openblas()
{
    git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
    cd OpenBLAS
    sed -i 's/ifeq/#ifeq/g' Makefile.riscv64
    sed -i 's/endif/#endif/g' Makefile.riscv64
    sed -i 's/CCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d -mtune=c920/CCOMMON_OPT += --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -march=rv64gcv_zfh -mabi=lp64d --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)/g'  Makefile.riscv64
    sed -i 's/FCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d -mtune=c920 -static/FCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64gcv_zfh -mabi=lp64d -static --sysroot=$(SYSROOT)/g' Makefile.riscv64
    sed -i 's/TARGET_FLAGS = -march=rv64gcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d/TARGET_FLAGS = --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -march=rv64gcv_zfh -mabi=lp64d/g' Makefile.prebuild
}

function setup_environment_vars()
{
    HOSTCC=clang
    CROSS_SUFFIX=llvm-
    ROOT=/opt/riscv
    CC=$ROOT/bin/clang
    FC=/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gfortran
    AR=$ROOT/bin/${CROSS_SUFFIX}ar
    RANLIB=$ROOT/bin/${CROSS_SUFFIX}ranlib
    SYSROOT=/opt/riscv/sysroot
    GCC_TOOLCHAIN=/opt/riscv
    CFLAGS=" -fuse-ld=lld --gcc-toolchain=$GCC_TOOLCHAIN"
}

function build_openblas()
{
    make -j4 TARGET=C910V CC=$CC FC=$FC AR=$AR RANLIB=$RANLIB HOSTCC=$HOSTCC SYSROOT=$SYSROOT CROSS_SUFFIX=$CROSS_SUFFIX CFLAGS="$CFLAGS" V=1
    if ! [ -d "$1" ]
    then
        echo "The defined installation directory $1 does not exist and will be created."
        mkdir -p "$1"
    fi
    make install PREFIX="$1"
    cd ..
}

DIR_FOR_SOURCES="$1"
INSTALLATION_DIR="$2"

if [ -z "$DIR_FOR_SOURCES" ]
then
    echo "A directory for OpenBLAS sources was not defined. The directory $HOME will be used by default."
    DIR_FOR_SOURCES="$HOME"
fi

if [ -z "$INSTALLATION_DIR" ]
then
    echo "Creating the default directory to install."
    sudo mkdir /opt/OpenBLAS
    sudo chown -R $USER /opt/OpenBLAS
    INSTALLATION_DIR="/opt/OpenBLAS"
    echo "A directory to install OpenBLAS was not defined. The directory $INSTALLATION_DIR will be used by default."
fi

echo "Directory for BLAS sources: $HOME"
echo "Installation directory: $INSTALLATION_DIR"
cd "$DIR_FOR_SOURCES"
clone_openblas
setup_environment_vars
build_openblas "$INSTALLATION_DIR"

echo "OpenBLAS was installed into $INSTALLATION_DIR"
```

3. the script llvm-clang-wrapper.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GCC_TOOLCHAIN=/opt/riscv
/opt/riscv/bin/clang --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -march=rv64gcv_zfh -mabi=lp64d -v --sysroot=$SYSROOT -fuse-ld=lld --gcc-toolchain=$GCC_TOOLCHAIN "$@"
```

4. the script llvm-clang++-wrapper.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GCC_TOOLCHAIN=/opt/riscv
/opt/riscv/bin/clang++ --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -march=rv64gcv_zfh -mabi=lp64d -v --sysroot=$SYSROOT -fuse-ld=lld --gcc-toolchain=$GCC_TOOLCHAIN "$@"
```

When I tried to use the standard Ubuntu cross-compilation GCC toolchain for RISC-V, I have no any compilation errors, and I get correct NumPy and SciPy packages for RISC-V.

More precisely, I did the following.

1. Install necessary deb-packages:

```bash
sudo apt install make cmake gcc g++ ccache gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu g++-riscv64-linux-gnu gfortran-riscv64-linux-gnu libgomp1-riscv64-cross libssl-dev meson
```

2. Download and build OpenBLAS:

```bash
mkdir wheels
cd wheels/
git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
cd OpenBLAS/
sed -i "s/CCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d -mtune=c920/CCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdc -mabi=lp64d/g" Makefile.riscv64
sed -i "s/FCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d -mtune=c920 -static/FCOMMON_OPT += -march=rv64imafdc -mabi=lp64d -static/g" Makefile.riscv64
make -j4 HOSTCC=gcc CC=riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc FC=riscv64-linux-gnu-gfortran ARCH=riscv64 TARGET=RISCV64_GENERIC
mkdir usr
make PREFIX=$HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/ install
```

3. Set up some environment variables:

```bash
export RISCV_GCC=riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc
export RISCV_GPP=riscv64-linux-gnu-g++
export RISCV_GFORTRAN=riscv64-linux-gnu-gfortran
export RISCV_LD=riscv64-linux-gnu-ld
export RISCV_AR=riscv64-linux-gnu-ar
```

4. Install crossenv package and create a virtual environment:

```bash
path-to-ubuntu-wsl-python3.9.14/bin/python3 -m pip install crossenv
path-to-ubuntu-wsl-python3.9.14/bin/python3 -m crossenv --cc $RISCV_GCC --cxx $RISCV_GPP --ar $RISCV_AR path-to-riscv-python3.9.14/bin/python riscv_cross_venv_stock
source riscv_cross_venv_stock/bin/activate
build-pip install wheel cython pybind11 pythran ply beniget gast pythran numpy==1.19.3
pip install wheel cython pybind11 pythran ply beniget gast pythran numpy==1.19.3
cd ..
```

5. Clone SciPy:

```bash
git clone --recurse-submodules -b v1.7.3 --depth 1 https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
cd scipy
```

6. Create the file site.cfg:

```bash
echo '[openblas]' >> site.cfg
echo 'libraries = openblas' >> site.cfg
echo "library_dirs = $HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/lib" >> site.cfg
echo "include_dirs = $HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/include" >> site.cfg
echo "runtime_library_dirs = $HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/lib" >> site.cfg
```

7. Set up the following environment variables:

```bash
export BLAS_DIR=$HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/
export OPEN_BLAS_DIR=$HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/
export F90=$RISCV_GFORTRAN
export F77=$RISCV_GFORTRAN
export LD=$RISCV_LD
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/wheels/OpenBLAS/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Build NumPy and SciPy:

```
pip wheel . -v -w ../wheels_stock
cd ../OpenBLAS/

cp riscv_cross_venv_stock/cross/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a riscv_cross_venv_stock/build/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a
cp riscv_cross_venv_stock/cross/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/lib/libnpyrandom.a riscv_cross_venv_stock/build/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/random/lib/libnpyrandom.a

cd ~/wheels/scipy/
pip wheel . -v -w ../wheels_stock
```

As a result, I got the correct wheel packages of NumPy and SciPy for RISC-V.

Also, I tried to use Clang/Clang++ and GFortran compiler from the standard Ubuntu 20.04 repos, but I got the strange linker error. Unfortunately, I forgot it.

I would like to know how I can build NumPy and SciPy using cross-compilation with Clang for RISC-V target machine.